# Add an argument to Python sh.Command

Tags: python

I'm having a localized issue with some open source software and I need to make a tweak to a python script to fix it, problem is I'm not at all familiar with Python, I need to specify the window position for omxplayer using the argument: `--win "0 0 1920 1080"` to stop it from clipping displayed videos by creating a window that's larger than the display resolution.

Here's the existing code:

```
player_args = ['omxplayer', uri]
player_kwargs = {'o': settings['audio_output'], '_bg': True,  '_ok_code': [0, 124]}
player_kwargs['_ok_code'] = [0, 124]
...
run = sh.Command(player_args[0])(*player_args[1:], **player_kwargs)
...
```

uri is the video file being played, I need to add the above mentioned argument to get it working properly, and I've tried appending it to the initial `omxplayer` string, and adding it to `player_args`, `player_kwargs`, and within the `sh.Command` at least ten different ways, none of which have worked.

Any help is appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: Difficult to tell without knowing what `sh` is... adding `'win': [0, 0, 1920, 1080]` to `player_kwargs` would seem logical given the example code though....

Comment: @JonClements Your suggestion was actually my first try too, the result was omxplayer executes fine, but without the additional argument. I just re-tried it passing the numbers as a string instead of an array ('0 0 1920 1080') and it worked.

Comment: Have you try `--win "0 0 1920 1080"` or `"win":"0 0 1920 1080"`. On Linux you can test it with `sh.Command('echo')` to print arguments on screen. For example `sh.Command('echo')({"win":[0,0,1920,1080]})` gives `--win=[0, 0, 1920, 1080]` but `sh.Command('echo')({"win":'"0 0 1920 1080"'})` gives `--win="0 0 1920 1080"`

Answer (score 0):

Adding 'win' : '0 0 1920 1080' to kwargs worked, thanks for the help guys!

```
player_kwargs = {'o': settings['audio_output'], '_bg': True,  '_ok_code': [0, 124], 'win': '0 0 1920 1080'}
```